# Clone form field with button below new created elements

Tags: jquery, html, forms

The code below add new fields when clicking the button "Add New".

Everything works fine, the only thing is that I'd like the new created fields to appear above the button rather than below. How could I do that?

```js
(function($) {
  "use strict";
  
  var itemTemplate = $('.example-template').detach(),
      editArea = $('.edit-area'),
      itemNumber = 1;
  
  $(document).on('click', '.edit-area .add', function(event) {
    var item = itemTemplate.clone();
    item.find('[name]').attr('name', function() {
      return $(this).attr('name') + '_' + itemNumber;
    });
    ++itemNumber;
    item.appendTo(editArea);
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.edit-area .rem', function(event) {
    editArea.children('.example-template').last().remove();
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.edit-area .del', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target),
        row = target.closest('.example-template');
    row.remove();
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden">
    <div class="example-template">
    <div class="form-inline">
    <input id="newContactLabel" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="newContactLabel">
   
    <input id="newContactContent" type="text" placeholder="Addr" name="newContactContent">
  
    <button type="button" class="del"> - </button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="edit-area">
    <div class="controls w3-center">
    <button type="button" class="add">Add Field</button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use prependTo method instead of appendTo. See below the code

```
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  var itemTemplate = $('.example-template').detach(),
      editArea = $('.edit-area'),
      itemNumber = 1;

  $(document).on('click', '.edit-area .add', function(event) {
    var item = itemTemplate.clone();
    item.find('[name]').attr('name', function() {
      return $(this).attr('name') + '_' + itemNumber;
    });
    ++itemNumber;
    item.prependTo(editArea);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.edit-area .rem', function(event) {
    editArea.children('.example-template').last().remove();
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.edit-area .del', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target),
        row = target.closest('.example-template');
    row.remove();
  });
}(jQuery));
```